# Dyanmic range change in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Hello i am writing a code finding difficult to execute this

```
Column E row 40 : 

P0.1, 

P0.2, 

P0.6 etc.

Column I row 39 : 

a2.0, 

P0.1, 

P0.2, 

P0.3. 

Column J row 39 : 

b2.0, 

P0.5, 

P0.2, 

P0.1.
```

similary 10 columns.

So i write a VBA to if first cell of the **row 40 column i I is red**. Than i check for duplicate values between **column E row 40 to row 50** and from **Column I row 40**.

That is if **row 40 column i I is red** than output will be

```
Column E row 40 : 

P0.1(SOME COLOR INDICATING DUPLICATE VALUE), 

P0.2(SOME COLOR INDICATING DUPLICATE VALUE), 

P0.3 etc.

Column I row 39 : 

a2.0(red color which is a condition), 

P0.1(SOME COLOR INDICATING DUPLICATE VALUE), 

P0.2(SOME COLOR INDICATING DUPLICATE VALUE), 

P0.6.
```

For this i have written code which is working fine.

that is

```
enter Public Sub nextphase33()

Dim wsPaste As Worksheet

 Dim wsFind As Worksheet

 Dim j As Long, i As Long

 Set wsFind = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(6)

For j = 9 To 33

If wsFind.Cells(39, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

    Range("E40:E46,I40:I73").Select

    Range("I40").Activate

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior

        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

        .Color = 150

        .TintAndShade = 0

    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Else

j = j + 1

End If

Next j

End Sub here
```

NOW my problem is that range is fixed.

If **red color in Column** i it will compare **column e and column i**

That is now i want to add a loop if first row column i is not red it should check for red color in column j is so compare and highlight duplicate with values between **Column E row 40 and Column j row 40**.
Which is not happening from my code please help me how to make range Dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using R1C1 reference style instead of A1 to select the range, so assuming that we had aliased the worksheet like this:

`dim wsFind as worksheet: set wsFind = activeWorkbook.sheets(6)`

the range selection in your original code would look like this:

```
wsFind.range(wsFind.cells(40,5), wsFind.cells(73,9))
wsFind.cells(40,9).Activate
```

You can use a variable `col` for the column number, and then change that to:

```
wsFind.range(wsFind.cells(40,5), wsFind.cells(73,col))
wsFind.cells(40,col).Activate
```

And then you could use your if clause that checks the interior color to set the `col` value, or if you are intending the affected column to be one less than `j` then all you have to do is start using `j-1` where I have `col`.

Comment: No.
This is just 1 part of the 6 macros.
i should have macro this way.

If clause should come first that cell is red choose some range of cells and check for duplicate values.

else
check for the next cell color and select different range of cells and find duplicate values.

i cannot use the range before IF condition.

Comment: i replaced

'this.range(this.cells(40,5), this.cells(73,9)).select
this.cells(40,9).Activate'

with

'this.range(this.cells(40,5), this.cells(73,col)).select
this.cells(40,col).Activate'

Defined variable col and worksheet as suggested but getting error like
"object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: In the immediate window, what do you get for 

`?this.name`

when you the error occurs?

Comment: i get this error "object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: It means that the assignment to this (a worksheet variable) never happened.  I see in your original code that you have two worksheets already declared, wsFind and wsPaste, and that you're working with wsFind.  I edited my original answer to use wsFind instead of this.  Let me know if that clears things up for you.